# delete from where id in subquery error

Tags: mysql, syntax-error

I ran this in mysql client shell on windows. I don't understand what the problem is. I know `delete from PageInfo where id` is correct. I know the subquery is correct. I think in is correct but I don't use it that often. This entire thing looks correct but i get a problem somewhere. I don't understand the error message.

How do i delete all the ids the subquery returns?

```
mysql> delete from PageInfo where id in ( select max(id) from PageInfo where pid
>=2758000 AND pid<2758100 group by pid having count(pid)>1 );
ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'PageInfo' for update in FROM
 clause
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL you cannot modify the same table which is a part of subquery.

more info at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html

[Workaround for your problem is described here.](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/06/23/how-to-select-from-an-update-target-in-mysql/)

Answer (score 4):

You could do it like this

```
delete from PageInfo where id = ( SELECT maxid FROM ( select max(id) as maxid from PageInfo where pid >=2758000 AND pid<2758100 group by pid having count(pid)>1) as tmp)
```

Comment: For a different query I did this and got `ERROR 1206 (HY000): The total number of locks exceeds the lock table size`. I guess I need to do it by code. +1 anyways

Answer (score 2):

from mysql [website](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subquery-errors.html). selecting and modifying from same table is not allowed as mentioned

**This error occurs in cases such as the following, which attempts to modify a table and     select from the same table in the subquery**

```
  Incorrectly used table in subquery:

 Error 1093 (ER_UPDATE_TABLE_USED)
  SQLSTATE = HY000
  Message = "You can't specify target table 'x'
 for update in FROM clause"
:
```