# Mysql update thows error in subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, select, subquery

I have this MySQL query, which is supposed to recalc the onlinetime of users when they go offline.

```
UPDATE isonline SET onlineTime = (
    (SELECT ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURTIME(4 ) ) * 1000 ) ) - //currentmillis
    (SELECT lastOnline FROM isonline WHERE nick = ? AND isOnline = 1 ) + 
    (SELECT onlineTime FROM isonline WHERE nick = ? AND isOnline = 1 )//oldonlinetime
) ,isOnline = false WHERE nick = ?;
```

Table Syntax:

```
+------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| nick       | text       | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| lastOnline | bigint(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| onlineTime | bigint(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| isOnline   | tinyint(4) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Formula: 
    newOnlineTime = oldOnlineTime + CurrentTimeInMS - lastTimeOnlineInMS

(MS = milliseconds)

Sadly I get this Error:

```
Error: ER_UPDATE_TABLE_USED: Table 'isonline' is specified twice, 
both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data
```

After searching an hour in google and trying many ideas I gave up searching, so I'm asking you to give me a hint how to fix this query.

If more information is needed: please ask

thanks to Shadow this is the solution:

```
UPDATE isonline SET onlineTime = (SELECT f FROM ((SELECT
((SELECT ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURTIME(4 ) ) * 1000 ) ) -
(SELECT lastOnline FROM isonline WHERE nick = "testuser" AND isOnline = 1 ) + 
(SELECT onlineTime FROM isonline WHERE nick = "testuser" AND isOnline = 1)) as f FROM dual) as t)
) ,isOnline = false WHERE nick = "testuser";
```

Comment: You should edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: In MySQL you cannot modify the same table which is a part of subquery.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [delete from where id in subquery error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12994768/delete-from-where-id-in-subquery-error)

Comment: @Gorden_Linoff: I hope this does it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known and irritating feature of mysql. You can get around this restriction by adding another layer of subselect:

```
UPDATE isonline SET onlineTime = (SELECT f FROM (SELECT
    ((SELECT ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURTIME(4 ) ) * 1000 ) ) - //currentmillis
    (SELECT lastOnline FROM isonline WHERE nick = ? AND isOnline = 1 ) + 
    (SELECT onlineTime FROM isonline WHERE nick = ? AND isOnline = 1) as f FROM dual) as t)//oldonlinetime
) ,isOnline = false WHERE nick = ?;
```

I hope I got the parentheses right :S

Comment: I cannot access sqlfiddle from where I'm now, so you need to provide me feedback verbally. But if it's an issue with parentheses, then I'm sure you can figure it out yourself.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as f FROM dual) as t)
) ,isOnline = false WHERE nick = "testuser"' at line 4  
Says SQLFiddle

Comment: I found your mistake: `UPDATE isonline SET onlineTime = (SELECT f FROM ((SELECT
    ((SELECT ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURTIME(4 ) ) * 1000 ) ) -
    (SELECT lastOnline FROM isonline WHERE nick = ? AND isOnline = 1 ) + 
    (SELECT onlineTime FROM isonline WHERE nick = ? AND isOnline = 1)) as f FROM dual) as t)
) ,isOnline = false WHERE nick = ?;`